# How can I fix typescript indent errors

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, eslint, indentation

I am writing some cloud functions using typescript/eslint for a project and cannot deploy because I am getting hundreds of errors like this:

```
35:1   error    Unexpected tab character                                       no-tabs
35:1   error    Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 2 tabs              indent
```

I am coming from Swift, so this is really weird/confusing for me. My VSCode tab size is set to 4 if this has anything to do with it. How can I fix this? Here is the code..

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp;
const db = admin.firestore();


interface Quote {
    id: string
    index: number
    authorName: string
    quote: string
    occupation: string
    imageURL: string
    webImageURL: string
}

interface User {
    id: string
    name: string
    currentQuote: [Quote]
}

interface QuoteData {
    id: string
    highestIndex: number
}

// get users to noitify, update new timme, get next quote, notify the user


export const taskRunner = functions.runWith({ memory: "2GB" }).pubsub
    .schedule("* * * * *").onRun(async (context) => {
        // consistent timestamp
        const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
        now.toDate().toTimeString();
        // query all documents ready to perform
        const query = db.collection("users").where("scheduleTime", "<=", now);

        const needToNotify = await query.get();

        if (needToNotify.docChanges.length <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        const adminDataQuery = db.collection("adminData").doc("quotesData");

        const adminData = await adminDataQuery.get();

        const quoteData = adminData.data() as QuoteData;

        // Loop through query results
        needToNotify.forEach(async (snapshot) => {
            const nextNotifTime = now.toDate();
            nextNotifTime.setDate(nextNotifTime.getDate() + 1);

            snapshot.ref.update({
                "scheduleTime": admin.firestore.Timestamp
                    .fromDate(nextNotifTime),
            });

            const userData = snapshot.data() as User;

            // Set temporary query for data
            let nextQuoteQuery = db.collection("quotes")
                .where("quoteIndex", "==", 0).limit(1);
            const defaultQuoteQuery = db.collection("quotes")
                .where("quoteIndex", "==", userData.currentQuote[0].index + 1)
                .limit(1);

            if (userData.currentQuote.length > 0) {
                const nextQuoteIndex = userData.currentQuote[0].index + 1;
                if (quoteData.highestIndex > nextQuoteIndex) {
                    return;
                }
                nextQuoteQuery = db.collection("quotes")
                    .where("quoteIndex", "==", nextQuoteIndex)
                    .limit(1);
            } else {
                nextQuoteQuery = defaultQuoteQuery;
            }

            const nextQuote = await nextQuoteQuery.get();

            // Should only contain one quote,
            // Since we called.limit(1) on the above query
            nextQuote.forEach(async (quoteData) => {
                const nextQuoteData = quoteData.data() as Quote;
                snapshot.ref.update({ currentQuote: [nextQuoteData] });

                // Push new quote notifications to users
                const message = {
                    notification: {
                        title: nextQuoteData.authorName,
                        body: nextQuoteData.quote,
                    },
                    topic: "quote",
                };
                await admin.messaging().send(message);
            });
        });
    });
```

Please let me know if I need to provide anything else as I am new to this language/editor. Thanks!

Comment: You should set the relevant eslint options ([no-tabs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-tabs), [indent](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/indent)) or even oblige it (indent with 4 spaces instead of tabs as the default settings require). See [the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/) on how to set eslint options

Comment: @kikon I ended up just changing the rules to ignore those errors, not sure if this is good practice though

Comment: I wouldn't worry, if it's only about style. You could use a tool like [`tsfmt`](https://github.com/vvakame/typescript-formatter) to change style at any time.

Answer (score 0):

On line 35, delete till you can't anymore, then indent with spaces. If you are using prettier in your prettierrc you can make it so it will always indent with spaces.